# grunt-contrib-compress exclude dot folder

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-compress

I'm using the grunt-contrib-compress task to compress the contents of the dist/ folder inside a ZIP archive. To do that I'm using the following configuration:

```
compress: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      archive: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>-<%= pkg.version %>.zip'
    },
    files: [{
      cwd: 'dist/',
      expand: true,
      src: [ '**' ]
    }]
  }
},
```

This is working great (all files are zipped), however, it also adds a folder called ".". I suppose that it's there because I'm including `**`, which also includes the current folder (a single dot).

For example:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this folder to be added to the ZIP?

I tried adding `!.` to my `src` but that did not seem to do the trick. I also read about the `dot` property, but setting it to `false` did not help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `src: ['**/*']` because `**` in minimatch is a "[Globstar](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch#features)" matcher, it matches everything including directory itself (the dot-directory). However, pattern `**/*` means "include all files and subdirectories" but dot-directory neither subdirectory nor file and it does not match it.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that, makes sense indeed, thanks!